# PhpStorm gives strange message

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phpstorm, target

My PhpStorm gives a strange error message on my JavaScript code (I'm new to this). Anyway I am quite confident that my code is correct. But PhpStorm still gives me an error message

> Unresolved variable valueAsDate

Any proposal what I can do better?

```
const startElement = document.querySelector('#date_start');

let startDate_oldValue;

startElement.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    startDate_oldValue = event.target.valueAsDate;
});
```

[image]

Comment: HTML elements don't have native `valueAsDate` property. Have you added that as a custom property?

Comment: `valueAsDate` and also `value` has the same propblem in PhpStorm, but both work fine in Chrome and also the `console.log(event)` show in the Console both properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE has no idea what your target element is, and `EventTarget` interface doesn't have `valueAsDate` property. You need to explicitly tell the IDE the type of the HTMLElement which is your target, like:

```
startElement.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    const myEl = /** HTMLInputElement*/ event.target;
    startDate_oldValue = myEl.valueAsDate;
});
```